# Correr aplicacion Django con runserver_plus y Werkzeug==2.1.2

Tags: python-3.x, django

Una vez utilizo el comando `python3 manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt` para levantar el servidor todo parece ir bien, la salida al parecer es correcta (Apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar esta forma); sin embargo, cuando cargo la página a visualizar corren varias excepciones antes de deternerse el servidor en una de ellas. Esta es:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 45190) 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()   
File "/home/<user>/Documents/Django/socialWeb/social_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 363, in handle
    super().handle()   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 425, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 413, in handle_one_request
    method()   
File "/home/<user>/Documents/Django/socialWeb/social_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 243, in run_wsgi
    self.environ = environ = self.make_environ()   
File "/home/<user>/Documents/Django/socialWeb/social_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runserver_plus.py", line 326, in make_environ
    del environ['werkzeug.server.shutdown'] 
KeyError: 'werkzeug.server.shutdown'
```

¿Cuál es la solución para este tipo de problema? Busqué información en el repositorio del proyecto pero la verdad no entendí o no encontré como solucionarlo en Django, esto es al parecer un problema desde la version 2.1 que entiendo eliminaron esta línea. El punto es como hacer que ahora con la versión actual que estoy usando funcione el proyecto. Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

De momento me baje a la versión 2.0.0 y ha funcionado para poder visualizar la aplicación correctamente.

```
pip install werkzeug==2.0.0
```

No se si esto sea lo mejor a hacer pero me ha servido.